# Can't update member variable

Tags: java, android

Somehow line `mResponseText = response.body().string();` isn't writing member variable. Instead it appears to be creating and logging it locally.

Any ideas why? The more I look at it the more clueless I'm getting :(

```
public class Gateway {
    private static final String TAG = Gateway.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    private String mResponseText = "[{'comment' : 'fake' , 'psn_nickname' : 'fake', 'created':'now', 'parent_class':''}]";



    public Gateway (String url, String json,  final Context context) {

        if(isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            //if network is available build request

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           // RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    //.post(body)
                    .build();

            Call call = client.newCall(request);
            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                //execute call
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                    // if request failed
                    Toast.makeText(context, "request failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    // if succeeded
                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                        mResponseText = response.body().string();
                        Log.v(TAG, "SETTING RESPONSE");
                        // THIS LOGS PROPER JSON LOADED FROM NETWORK
                        Log.v(TAG, mResponseText);

                    } else {

                        //alertUserAboutError(context);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Something wrong with response", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public String getResponse () {
        Log.v(TAG, "GETTING RESPONSE");
        // THIS LOGS FAKE SAMPLE JSON --- WTF???
        Log.v(TAG, mResponseText);
        return mResponseText;
    }


    // check if network is available
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        return isAvailable;
    }
    /*
    private void alertUserAboutError(Context c) {
        AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(c.getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }
    */
}
```

Here's the code that's using this class

```
Gateway gateway = new Gateway(mCommentURL, "", this);
String mJsonData = gateway.getResponse();
```

**EDIT** Code update - removed `extends Activity`

Comment: You're `Gateway` appears to be an `Activity`, yet you're not overriding any lifecycle method, but instead do a lot of work in a non-standard constructor. This seems a bit iffy. How exactly is this supposed to work? What are you doing with `Gateway`?

Comment: @ci_ it is not activity,it is class for getting json object i guess

Comment: `public class Gateway extends Activity `

Comment: So, show how you're using it.

Comment: You're right. It isn't an activity and it is used as a central point to get all kinds of json requests from web app. I extended from `Activity` to get access to it's method `getFragmentManager()`. I commented it out and removed extension. No luck -- it appears problem is elsewhere.

Updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `getResponse()` too early. The async operation has not completed yet and the value returned is the one you initialize there in the first place, not the one written in the `Callback`.

Put the code that uses the response in the `Callback`, or call that code from the callback.

Comment: To other newbs trying to do the same - here's how to do those Async tasks - http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/